# Is it possible to add an include directive inside of a class definition?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am currently working on a project where we have a shared set of headers. Now we want add some private fields without having to put those declarations directly in the shared headers.

Someone brought up the following:

```
namespace something {
    class Foo {
    public:
        Foo();

        void doFoo();
    private:
#if __has_include("foo_private.hpp")
#include "foo_private.hpp"
#endif
    };
}
```

Inside the `_private.hpp` headers we would then place the private fields for that class. When there are only default datatypes (int, bool, etc) this works fine(ish). But as soon as you put an include inside the `_private.hpp` file, for example #include  everything breaks.

It is giving the following error `expected unqualified-id before ‘namespace’` which as I understand is quite logical, since you're trying to define a namespace inside of a class.

Example _private.hpp file

```
#ifndef DUMMY_PRIVATE_TEMPLATE_INCLUDES_FOO_PRIVATE_HPP
#define DUMMY_PRIVATE_TEMPLATE_INCLUDES_FOO_PRIVATE_HPP

#include <string>

int mySecretNumber;

std::string mySecretString;

#endif
```

Now my question is, is there any way to trick the preprocessor, or somehow get the same results with a different solution?

Comment: Please don't use HTML/CSS/JS snippets for non-HTML/CSS/JS code.

Comment: Oops, terribly sorry

Comment: It is possible, but it is not possible to place `#include <string>` inside class definition. `Now we want add some private fields without having to put those declarations directly in the shared headers.` That is either inheritance or pimpl idiom. In either case, putting `#include` in the middle of class definition will be hell to maintain.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?  You said you don't want member variables in the public headers, but why?

Comment: If this is an attempt to hide implementation details in a private undisturbed header, it's doomed to fail. The C++ object model requires for all code everywhere to see the same class layout. The pimpl idiom may be something you should investigate instead.

Comment: You may include whereever you want and whatever you want, but you should at least make sure that it makes any sense.

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace something {
    class Foo {
    public:
        Foo();

        void doFoo();
    private:
#if __has_include("foo_private.hpp")
#include "foo_private.hpp"
#endif
    };
}
```

If that code is including a file that looks like this:

```
#ifndef DUMMY_PRIVATE_TEMPLATE_INCLUDES_FOO_PRIVATE_HPP
#define DUMMY_PRIVATE_TEMPLATE_INCLUDES_FOO_PRIVATE_HPP

#include <string>

int mySecretNumber;

std::string mySecretString;

#endif
```

Then you end up with this (though in reality, the #includes themselves would resolve to the contents of `<string>`, etc.):

```
namespace something {
    class Foo {
    public:
        Foo();

        void doFoo();
    private:
        #ifndef DUMMY_PRIVATE_TEMPLATE_INCLUDES_FOO_PRIVATE_HPP
        #define DUMMY_PRIVATE_TEMPLATE_INCLUDES_FOO_PRIVATE_HPP

        #include <string>

        int mySecretNumber;

        std::string mySecretString;

        #endif
    };
}
```

Perhaps that shows your issue?  You're including "string" in the middle of your class, but it needs to be included at the global namespace scope of your file.

Instead, include string at the top of the outer header, don't use include guards in the private header, and only put the body of the code you want pasted into your class into that private header.  For that reason, you might not call it a ".hpp" file but something else to make it clear it's not a normal header.

Additionally, the __has_include feature seems dubious, because if your private header is missing you probably do not want it to compile to an empty class.

Worse, if you compile some translation unit that finds the header, and then compile another translation unit that does not find the private header, you will end up with two different definitions of your class, violating the One Definition Rule -- which is undefined behavior, no diagnostic required.  Really nasty stuff (assuming your builds succeeds at all.)

I'm not a big fan of this kind of hiding, as it will make it hard for editors to properly show your code, to colorize and index your private header, or otherwise work with the code in a normal way.  You might consider looking at the PIMPL idiom for hiding the implementation of a class in its .cpp file, so users of the header do not have to see it at all.